# Operate on columns based on other column contents in pandas

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Coming from R, I cannot figure out how to make kinda vectorized operations on one dataframe column by utilizing other columns, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'s':['Big bear eats cat','cute cat sleeps'],'a':['bear','cat']})
```

Now I just want to replace (other operations could be split) rowwise the occurrence of a in s with ANIMAL so it looks like this:

```
0    Big ANIMAL eats cat
1    cute ANIMAL sleeps
```

In R data.table (with vectorized functions) I would just write something like

```
df[,s:=str_replace(s,a,"ANIMAL")]
```

I saw I might be able to use apply but that still seemed very complex for such an easy case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution doing the same as I am used from in R by vectorizing (numpy needed) the str.replace:

```
import numpy as np

df['s']=np.vectorize(str.replace)(df['s'],df['a'],"ANIMAL")

print(df)
      a                    s
0  bear  Big ANIMAL eats cat
1   cat   cute ANIMAL sleeps
```

Comment: Nice solution, ~2.5x faster than a list comprehension for large dataframes.

Comment: The only problem is it doesn't split by word. So `catheter` would be caught (inappropriately). Likely this is the source of the performance difference.

Comment: yes that's true - I experimented a little bit more and in this case I will just use `re.sub` instead of `str.replace` which allows regular expressions. I am not sure about the performance as patterns cannot be compiled in advance (because they depend on the column content) but performance is not an issue yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
df['s'] = [' '.join([i if i!=a else 'ANIMAL' for i in s.split()]) \
           for a, s in zip(df['a'], df['s'])]

print(df)

      a                    s
0  bear  Big ANIMAL eats cat
1   cat   cute ANIMAL sleeps
```

Comment: This works but seems to be a very complex, non-generic solution to me

Comment: I agree it's not "Pandorable" - on the other hand, Pandas `str` functions are notoriously slow. You've come up with a nice solution with `np.vectorize`.